# does graph pattern matching take space in memory?

Tags: neo4j, pattern-matching

In neo4j,when making a graph pattern matching,when you create a pattern node or pattern relationship,will it be saved?

I mean will it take a space in memory,just like when you create a node or relationship in graph database?

or it will be created just virtually,and does not any take space in memory?

I mean the pattern nodes and pattern relationships will take space and will be saved like nodes and relationships in neo4j graph db?or not they will disappear as soon as the code finishes?

Answer (score 1):

It will take some space in memory while it's being processed but the results won't be stored on disk if that's the question.

The cypher execution plans are cached so that they don't have to be recomputed every time but again that's in transient memory rather than anything persistent.

Comment: if I create it in java api (I mean I do not use cypher),will it take space in memory?I don not mean results,I mean the pattern nodes and pattern relationships?

Comment: I mean the pattern nodes and pattern relationships will take space and will be saved like nodes and relationships in neo4j graph db?or not they will disappear as soon as the code finishes?

Comment: They disappear, they only live as long as your query runs.